# BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic() returns NULL on Android 6

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We developed a little hardware piece that works with Bluetooth Low Energy. When connecting from an *Android 5*, all services and their characteristics are discovered successfully.

However, we tried with 3 *Android 6* devices, and even though the services are found correctly, their characteristics return `null` all the time.

I made sure the `UUID`s are correct by logging all the discovered *services*, *characteristics* & descriptors.

*Android 5:*

```
service [uuid]:[00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
service [uuid]:[00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
service [uuid]:[5765536d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00005765-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
        descriptor [uuid]:[00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
service [uuid]:[5765536e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00005764-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
        descriptor [uuid]:[00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
```

*Android 6:*

```
service [uuid]:[00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
service [uuid]:[00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
    characteristic [uuid]:[00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
service [uuid]:[5765536d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
service [uuid]:[5765536e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
```

Is there any known issue provoking this? I am using `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothLeScanner`.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked on Android 6 after we changed the service `UUID`'s from:

```
5765536d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
5765536e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

To:

```
3032454c-426b-7261-5074-72616d536557
3031454c-426b-7261-5074-72616d536557
```

It also worked when we reduced the `UUID`'s size from 32bits to 16bits, this means, the first four digits being zero `0000XXXX`.

Comment: I think I'm running into the same issue but can't find any android device around that have OS 6, how did you go about finding the relationship between the two UUIDs ? did you manage to find any resources about this ?